# How to mapper a tree json object using jackson to List<>

Tags: java, json, hibernate

After i execute a query, the result is converted to JSON. The format is like:

```
[
    {
        "version": "1.0.1",
        "device.id": 1234,
        "user.id": 1234,
        "device.platform": "IOS",
        "lastActivity": null,
        "id": 987,
        "when": "2017-08-05",
        "device.platformVersion": "1.2.2",
        "endPointArn": "arn-here-123"
    },
    {
        "version": "1.0.2",
        "device.id": 2345,
        "user.id": 9876,
        "device.platform": "IOS",
        "lastActivity": null,
        "id": 753,
        "when": "2017-08-05",
        "device.platformVersion": "1.2.2",
        "endPointArn": "arn-here-123"
    }
]
```

I need to mapper this json for a List<> objects where:

```
public class DeviceUser {
  private Integer id;
  private String version;
  private Date when;
  private String endPointArn;
  private Device device;
  private User user;
}
```

we can see the keys with attrObject.fieldObject (e.g: "device.id": 2345) and i dont see the way to convert for espected format.
The final format spected is:

```
[
    {
        "version": "1.0.1",
        "user": {
            "id": 1234
        },
        "device": {
            "id": 1234,
            "platform": "IOS",
            "platformVersion": "1.2.2"
        },
        "lastActivity": null,
        "id": 987,
        "when": "2017-08-05",
        "endPointArn": "arn-here-123"
    },
    {
        "user": {
            "id": 9876
        },
        "device": {
            "id": 2345,
            "platform": "IOS",
            "platformVersion": "1.2.2"
        },
        "version": "1.0.2",
        "lastActivity": null,
        "id": 753,
        "when": "2017-08-05",
        "endPointArn": "arn-here-123"
    }
]
```

Comment: you could work with annotations https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations

Comment: with the new json, you have to create nested objects, or work with json-path

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jackson, try to annotate the fields (or the getters/setters) with `JsonPropety` annotation.

Like this:

`@JsonProperty("device.id")
private Device device;`

Answer (score 0):

So, i resolved this case using a new transformer on result set. The transformer in really just iterate on result and search for ".". Using reflexion. I guess this a poor strategy. And so, i accept new answers.

The transformer that i used is: [AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer](https://github.com/samiandoni/AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer)